# How do i stop this code from executing using a stop button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a start button which triggers a function.

```
<button type="button" onclick="start()">START</button>
```

Here is my java script

```
function start() {
var cookieValue = document.getElementById('balance').getAttribute('value');
 if (cookieValue == 0){
         alert("insufficient funds");
     exit();
 }else{
    var url = $("#url").val() + '.php?check=';
    console.log(url);
    var line = $("#ccs").val();
    var linesend = line.split("\n");
    linesend.forEach(function(value, index) {
        setTimeout(
            function start() {
            Array.prototype.randomElement = function () {
            return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]
            }

                $.ajax({
                    url: url + value,
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.match("success")) {
                            removeline();
                            live(result);
                        }else {
                            removeline();
                            dead(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },2500 * index);
    });
}
}
```

How do I stop this `2500 * index` loop right here using a stop function? Cause I wanted a stop button for this one

Comment: So question is how do you stop setTimeout??

Comment: yes using a stop function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value

Comment: I need help on implementing it on my code above, it does not work.

Comment: well since you are invoking multiple timers, you would need an array of timeouts and loop over it.

Answer (score -1):

Clear timeout?

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(start, 2500*index);
 clearTimeout(timeout);
```